# How is the value of R1 calculated in this xenon flash circuit?

Tags: power-supply, flyback

I have made a voltage boosting circuit using a flyback transformer by using the first part of a xenon flash circuit.

Instead of an H1061 transistor with R1 of 620 Ω I used a 2SC4834 which works with a value of R1 of 68 Ω which I arrived at by trial and error. Is there a way of more accurately calculating what the value of R1 should be for different transistors / primary winding resistance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All I can say calculating an exact value of R1 is a big challenge where you must to know almost everything (voltages, currents, etc..).

*But simply:*

1. Find out what current flows in primary according the secondary current from output voltage and load.
2. From primary current calculate the base current needed Ib = Ic/Beta
3. The rough value of R1 is given by (12v-1.4v)/Ib
   (1.4v is a two diode drop, diode + Vbe)

As you can see the value of R1 is very Beta dependent, so most probably the new transistor has a different Beta:

H1061 Hfe = 60-200
2SC4834 Hfe = 10-25

Comment: Thanks Michal , that's helped my understanding , I thought that it was possibly linked to the Hfe.